# WHOIS information is updated but DNS is not updating

Tags: dns

I have a domain name which i have changed the A records and DNS records for at the same time on the 25th, however the A record propagated in about 24 hours but only half of them however its been almost 7 days since then and the DNS still hasnt updated.

```
Domain name:
jmeducation.co.uk

Data validation:
Nominet was able to match the registrant's name and address against a 3rd party data source on 10-Dec-2012

Registrar:
123-Reg Limited t/a 123-reg [Tag = 123-REG]
URL: http://www.123-reg.co.uk

Relevant dates:
Registered on: 24-Mar-2009
Expiry date: 24-Mar-2016
Last updated: 25-Feb-2016

Registration status:
Registered until expiry date.

Name servers:
ns1.jmdomains.uk.plesk-server.com
ns2.jmdomains.uk.plesk-server.com

WHOIS lookup made at 09:09:49 02-Mar-2016
```

The WHOIS info is correct, but the DNS is just not updating to the DNS shown here.

any help on why it has not updated yet would be much appreciated, also since the 25th we have re-updated to the same DNS servers shown and it is still not updating.

Comment: DNS Lookup looks good: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3ajmeducation.co.uk&run=toolpage Both name servers are reporting the domain name.

Comment: Hi, https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/jmeducation.co.uk reports otherwise at the moment and so do other sites